# "Infinitely close" intuition for a topological space containing two points

Tags: general-topology, intuition

I'm trying to understand a point made in a set of lecture notes on topological spaces. It takes $X = \{p,q\}$, and declares that the open sets are $\emptyset$, $\{p\}$, and $\{p,q\}$. These certainly satisfy the axioms for topology. The comment in the notes are:

> Roughly speaking, this means that "one point is infinitely close to the other, but not vice versa," which is not something that would normally a rise in a geometric setting.

I'm struggling to understand what this means. This is surely talking about $p$ and $q$. I think it is trying to say that the fact that $\{p,q\}$ is open implies one of $p$ and $q$ is "infinitely close to the other," but the fact that $\{p\}$ itself is open implies it isn't "infinitely close to $q$." I'm struggling to understand this characterization of openness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that $\{p,q\}$ is open doesn't tell you anything--the whole space is always open.  Rather, it is the fact that $\{q\}$ is *not* open which tells you $p$ is "infinitely close to $q$".  Indeed, this says that *every* neighborhood of $q$ contains $p$ (since the only such neighborhood is $\{p,q\}$).  If you think of neighborhoods as containing all "sufficiently close points", this means that $p$ is always "sufficiently close" to $q$, no matter how close you want it to be.

On the other hand, since $\{p\}$ is open, $q$ is *not* "infinitely close to $p$".  There is some neighborhood of $p$ that does not contain $q$, so $q$ is "far enough from $p$" to be outside that neighborhood.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Just to be sure, by neighborhood, are you using the definition "an open set containing the point," as opposed to Rudin's definition where a neighborhood is, essentially, an open ball?

Comment: Does Rudin really define a neighborhood to be a ball? I think you might have misread Rudin, but if that is Rudin’s meaning, completely forget it. Nobody uses that definition. @JohnT

Comment: @JohnT: A neighbourhood of a point is any set containing it in its interior.

Comment: John’s non-Rudin definition and @tomasz’s definition are the two (different) definitions of neighborhood I know. The second (tomasz’s) allows any set which contains an open set which contains $x.$

Comment: I had tomasz's definition in mind but for this particular space it doesn't make a difference since there are so few sets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My understanding of Rudin is that a neighborhood of radius $r$ of a point $p$, $N_r (p)$, is defined as the set of $q$ such that $d(p,q) < \epsilon$. This is the same thing as the open ball $B_r (p)$, right?

Comment: @JohnT Yes. And that works for metric spaces (and one can get to tomasz's alternative definition by saying a neighborhood of $p$ is any set *containing* an open ball centered on $p$) but in a general topological setting there is no such thing as "an open ball centered on p" and one needs to replace it with "an open set containing $p$" or "a basic open set containing $p$".

Comment: Rudin defines “the neighborhood of radius $r$” as a ball, but that doesn’t define neighborhood in general, just a specific kind of neighborhood. @JohnT

Comment: @JohnT: You're right, there is a mild conflict in terminology. This is a different, although not unrelated, as noted by others, notion of a neighbourhood. This can be defined for an arbitrary subset of a metric space.  I think typically, when someone says "neighbourhood", he means what I wrote in my first comment. When referring to $N_r(A)$ for $A\subseteq X$ (where $X$ is a metric space), they would likely be more explicit in what they mean.